# Ceridian Dayforce HRIS API location

Tags: rest, api, documentation, integration

Our company is considering connecting [Ceridian](http://www.ceridian.com/index.html) [Dayforce](http://www.ceridian.com/human-capital-management/index.html) HR management system with our product.

Now I was asked to estimate required time and effort it would require to do so. The problem is, I can't find documentation source for the API. Dayforce *seem* to provide an API, for example they have [this](http://www.ceridian.com/resources/data-sheets/dayforce-web-services.html) article that *seem* to state they support API integration, but data sheet itself is one page size and written in purely non-technical way.

I am wondering: is there any public source of such documentation? If there is none, does this mean that there is no API available or that documentation is only provided to developer once they finish approvement process of some kind?

Comment: So did you ever get around to getting this working? How did you deal with access levels and the api write capabilites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to contact your account manager at Ceridian to get details. They do have detailed documentation, just not freely available.

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'detailed' per se. It's more like a dumpster fire.

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed an API.  Integration can be performed using SOAP or REST.

You will need to request from Ceridian that they create a test instance for you.  After this, it's a good idea to ask for assistance in creating a user role for the purposes of accessing web services.  I had some serious pitfalls in this process since it is not reasonable to ask your own HR staff (who likely only use the front end) to know how to do this for you.  Ask Ceridian's support team instead.

I have been working on this for about two weeks.  I have successfully performed GET and PATCH requests (both using Postman and in code) but creating a new employee with POST is not as straightforward as the documentation makes it out to be.  There seem to be many snags along the way and Ceridian is not very cooperative in providing clear explanations when problems occur (they don't really provide any support on these things, and they make this fairly clear in their documentation).  Their support staff are not really development people, so their knowledge in this domain is likely limited as can be expected.

With that said, I can say that the documentation may seem to be detailed, but be aware that the detail ends after the 'happy path' cases are outlined.

Comment: Do you have a Github repository with the code? Or even a summary of how you managed to get this working in Postman?

Answer (score 1):

Dayforce is introducing Restful web services in their new realease 53. If that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please however try to make sure you do answer the question. In this case the OP wanted to find documentation.